# How do I overcome overcome this error of ACL and Firewall?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake

I am getting error like given below:

> Access to https://YourAccount.azuredatalakestore.net/web/v1/ is denied. Make sure the ACL and firewall rule is correctly configured in the Azure Data Lake Store account.

How do I overcome overcome this error of ACL and Firewall?

Comment: Don't share your URL in public forum like stackoverflow.

Comment: Did you set IP address range for data access?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-secure-data

Did you enabled firewall and Allow access to Azure service "ON"?
What way are you connecting to DataLakeStorage?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have added your account to the ACL, follow this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-secure-data#filepermissions

And set IP address range for data access, follow this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-secure-data#set-ip-address-range-for-data-access